# Is it possible to open ContentPage when OnMessageReceived from firebase cloud messaging?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to open a contentPage when fcm sends push notification. I have learned how to open a contentPage when the 'push notification' is clicked. My question is how do I follow the same approach but open a contentPage without clicking on push notification. Is this possible or will I have to try another approach to do this?

I went through this article: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/155333/open-contentpage-when-tap-push-notification-using-firebasepushnotificationplugin

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try detecting the OnMessageReceived method of the custom FirebaseMessagingService class to perform the navigation directly. Check the code: `public class FirebaseNotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);
        ...
        Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page_1());
    }
    ...
}`

Answer (score 0):

> how do I follow the same approach but open a content page without ... click on push notification

Try detecting the **OnMessageReceived** method of the custom `FirebaseMessagingService` class to perform the navigation directly. The page will be opened when the device receives the message.

Check the code:

```
public class FirebaseNotificationService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);
        ...
        Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page_1());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This piece of code works only when the app is in foreground. I want to make something when the app is killed or in background the app opens up. End result will be something like what alarm app do i.e. when I received notification I will show AlarmScreen (ContentPage) to user

Comment: Since Android 8.0, background service is limited. If you want to make the service is always working, try using a `ForgroundService`. Tutorial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/#background-execution-limits-in-android-80  Check the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60028587/background-service-with-isolated-process-in-xamarin-forms/60032046#60032046